# Pushing JSON with internal relational data to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, database-design, mongoose-schema

I have a JSON I would like to put into my mongo db database. My JSON holds some relational data. This data is internal to that JSON, I don't need to store this anywhere else. Example:

```
{
 title: "John film list"
 films [
   {
    title: "Once upon a time in Hollywood"
    director: '1a' //referencing the director using an ID of type string
   },
   {
    title: "Some film with empty director field",
    director: ''
   }
 ],
 directors: [
  {
    id: '1a', //find the director here
    name: 'Tarantino'
  }
 ]
}
```

I do not need to store anything centrally (I don't need a big list of directors somewhere), but in this very document I need to be able to look up the director (`1a`) and get back Tarantino.

I managed to push this JSON format to MongoDB. However, it gives my schemas new ids (`_id`-field) and I am confused now as to how to relate the two properly in mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default unique primary key in the MongoDB document is _id. When you insert a new document, it returns the unique id of the record that inserted (created).

The value inside this id is ObjectId who creates based on time. you can read about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

If you want to use your own value for the _id, have to pass it when you call the insert, like this:

```
db.directors.insertOne({_id: '1a', name: 'Tarantino'})
```